# display large amount landmarks in different scales in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-server

I have large amount of Landmarks, I want to display on map using ArcGIS Server. I want to display these landmarks based on the scale, some thing like

```
 Scale 1:1000000 display 3-10 landmarks only
 Scale 2:500000 display 10-20 landmarks only
 Scale 3:100000 display 20-100 landmarks only
 Scale 4:5000 display 100-300 landmarks only
```

The displaying would be random landmarks or based on some filtering. its something like using QuadTree, or some thing like google. as far you zoom more landmarks appears.
It is also some thing like Maplex labeling (buffer labeling), but this time feature displaying not labeling.

How I can do that without to have multiple copy of layer with different scales and different queries

Answer (score 2):

So, you have a feature class with points representing landmarks. You store it in a geodatabase and want to publish this feature class as a map service which can be accessible to the clients.

You will need to add this feature class as a layer to a map document and publish a map service. There is no standard functionality built into ArcGIS Server that can do smart scale-based filtering. This is because the user requirements can be so diverse, so there will never be a simple guaranteed solution for this fairly difficult problem.

### 1. Web-based access

If this map service will be accessed from a web browser via a web application built with the ArcGIS JavaScript API, you have multiple options on generalizing your data (including using [clusters](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html) and [point thinning](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html)). There is Geometry service available in ArcGIS Server, which can be helpful for this kind of thing. There are some built-in methods inside REST API, too, that can help you with generalization on the querying stage. Please refer to the [JS Help page](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/) for details.

### 2. Map service SOE

If you will access the map service not from a JS-based web application, you will need to customize the map service capabilities by building into a smart algorithm that will thin/cluster your points on-the-fly as ArcGIS Server will handle user requests. This can be done by developing something called Server Object Extension ([SOE](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/about-extending-services.htm)). The requests that will be processed will get modified response containing not all the points in the extent but only those your algorithm will find best representative. You will need to write in Java or .NET (C#/VB). It's going to be a lot of work.

### 3. Map document: many layers

My recommendation is to use multiple layers within the map document. This is the best practices Esri has embraced, and it proved to be an efficient solution. In terms of performance, you will win a lot by pre-creating multiple versions of your landmarks feature class each of which will be generalized. Then you will have multiple layers in the map document each referring to an individual feature class that should be visible within a certain scale range. This of course works well if your data is relatively static or you can automate generation of feature class on a daily basis (say every night).

For generalizing data in ArcGIS Desktop before serving multiple feature classes, there are multiple approaches available. Look at the [Grouping Analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/how-grouping-analysis-works.htm), [Integrate](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/integrate.htm) GP tool, and the [Cartography](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/cartography-toolbox/an-overview-of-the-cartography-toolbox.htm) toolbox. Just by googling "generalize points ArcGIS" you will find a bunch of ways to generalize your points.

Answer (score 1):

To strenthen Alex's first point, if you are indeed using JavaScript, check out clustering. I implemented Rene Rubalcava's [ClusterFeatureLayer](https://github.com/odoe/esri-clusterfeaturelayer) in a JS API web application - his sample application in the repo is really easy to plug your service into to test.